# how to make discord bot disconnects the user from the room?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@bot.command()
async def disconnect(ctx, time: int):
    if time <= 0:
        await ctx.send("time must be greater than 0")
        return

    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, Disconnect in {time} s")
    await asyncio.sleep(time)

    voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    if voice_channel:
        try:
            voice_client = await voice_channel.connect()
            await voice_client.disconnect()
            await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, Disconnected")
        except:
            await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, unable to Disconnect")
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, You are not on the voice channel")
```

It's not working, am I missing something? I typed !disconnect 5 , after 5 seconds it says unable to Disconnect , that means there must be an error .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To kick a user from a voice channel, use the [`Member.move_to`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=voicechannel#discord.Member.move_to) method and passing `None` as the channel argument:

```py
@bot.command()
async def disconnect(ctx, time: int):
    if time <= 0:
        return await ctx.send("Time must be greater than 0")

    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, disconnect in {time}s")
    await asyncio.sleep(time)

    voice_state = ctx.author.voice
    if voice_state:
        try:
            await ctx.author.move_to(None)  # kick user
        except Exception:
            await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, unable to Disconnect")
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, You are not on the voice channel")
```